# unable to set data-theme and properties to button in ui-block of grid layout in jquerymobile

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile

```
    {
    <div  class = "ui-grid-d" >
        <div class = "ui-block-a" >
            <div class = "ui-grid-a">
                 <div class = "ui-block-a">
                     <a id = "button-prop"  data-role="button" data-theme = "b" ><h3 id="text-pos">0</h3></a>
                  </div>  //end of block-a
                  <div class = "ui-block-b">
```

### 1

```
                  </div>  //end of block-b
              </div>  //end of grid-a
          </div> //end of block-a of grid-d
          <div data-role = "ui-block-b">
                      ----
          </div>
          <div data-role = "ui-block-c">
                      ----
          </div>
          <div data-role = "ui-block-d">
                      ----
          </div>
          <div data-role = "ui-block-e">
                      ----
          </div>
    </div> //end of grid-d
```

In CSS:
    {
        div.ui-btn{
          styles of button
        }
        div.ui-btn ui-btn-inner{
          styles of button content
        }
    }

I'm developing an iPhone app using Phonegap and jquerymobile. In this, i created one grid layout and in block of grid layout i created button. But i can't set properties and theme to that button . Please tell me the solution

But these styles couldn't effect the button